# How to clear webcache of Spotify App

Tags: spotify

I am developing an app for Spotify. I noticed that the Javascript is not always updated when I reload my app. So I guess the cache of the internal webengine is not cleared.

Does anybody know how I can force that? The Chrome developer tools have an option to disable the cache. The Spotify developer tools don't seem to offer such an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've alse had this issue when trying to reload with key command (<kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> on Mac).
Try "right click -> reload" instead. That works just fine for me.

Comment: I used the menu but that did not help, either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed [video guide on clearing Spotify cache](https://www.mrhack.io/blog/how-to-clear-spotify-cache-video-2/).

In short, on Spotify mobile app:
Go to Home Screen -> Settings -> Storage -> Delete Cache.